# Retrieving Google User Information once logged in (Meteor)

Tags: authentication, meteor, user-profile, google-signin, accounts

I've not been able to show my google users name or profile picture. This is what I have so far...

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    if (options.profile) {
        options.profile.picture = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + user.services.google.id;
        user.profile = user.services.google.picture;
    }
    return user;
});
```

and I'm showing this in my profile template

```
            {{#if currentUser}}
                <img scr="{{currentUser.profile.picture}}" alt="{{currentUser.username}}">
            {{/if}}
```

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem. What if I want to get more information from the user such as gender, etc?

This is what happens when you type Meteor.user() in the console

```
 Object
_id: "BoH9pAN8G7Xj2cWkT"
profile: Object
name: "redacted"
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() {
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() {
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() {
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() {
constructor: function Object() {
get __proto__: function () {
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() {
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() {
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() {
set __proto__: function () {
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() {
toString: function toString() {
valueOf: function valueOf() {
__proto__: Object
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() {
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() {
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() {
length: 1
name: "__lookupGetter__"
__proto__: function () {
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() {
constructor: function Object() {
get __proto__: function () {
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() {
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() {
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() {
set __proto__: function () {
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() {
toString: function toString() {
valueOf: function valueOf() {
```

Comment: Maybe try `user.profile.picture = user.services.google.picture;`

Comment: Sadly that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after being authenticated with google (with the package accounts-google), I wanted to get more information about the user, especially the profile picture.

Sadly a :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   console.log(Meteor.user());
});
```

in the client js would output me the same result than yours, I could not access to nothing but

```
{{currentUser.profile.name}}
```

I connected to the database with Robomongo and looked for the "users" table. Surprisingly, all the fields got from google were here.

[image]

I thought that maybe the client had no access to all of those fields by default. So I added a publication in the server js file to get all of the current user data. Then made the client js file subscribing to the publication.

Server JS :

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
   return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

Client JS :

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Then I was able to get all the fields needed

Client HTML :

```
{{currentUser.services.google.id}}
{{currentUser.services.google.email}}
{{currentUser.services.google.picture}}
```